# Synchronization streams in a specific queue using Mutex

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, mutex

There is a slight problem with threads, please tell me how to solve it or at least in which direction to look for, looking for a long time, but so far without success ... Here's the problem: there are 3 threads, they can run in any order (321;213;123...). In whatever order flows we would not run, they need to work out in the order 1,2,3. For this purpose, use thread synchronization with ONE mutex. In advance thank you.

Comment: Is this homework ? What have you tried ?

Comment: I tried to do this but i can't!

Comment: Why the heck would you use a mutex in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You should keep a variable set to `0`. When the first thread runs it sets the varialbe to `1`.
The second thread waits before the variable is set to `1`, sets it to `2` and starts working. And the same for the third one. Use mutex to synchronize checking/setting the variable. Also preferabley use timeout or events for checking the variable.

Comment: You mean the syntax? I've never used mutex and thread on c#. I just know how they work from other programming languages )))